# Mocking void functions using EasyMock with dynamic behaviour

Tags: testing, easymock

I need to mock a void function with EasyMock such that the first call returns an Exception, while the next succeeds.

For example:

```
this.myObject.move((String) EasyMock.anyObject());
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once().andThrow(new RetryableDependencyException());
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work as the second expectLastCall() cannot find any call.

Have you tried this:

```
this.myObject.move((String) EasyMock.anyObject());
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once().andThrow(new RetryableDependencyException());
this.myObject.move((String) EasyMock.anyObject());
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
```

I know it's a bit verbose but it should get you sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest is

```
myObject.move(anyString());
expectLastCall().andThrow(new RetryableDependencyException()).asStub();
```

which assumes that is doesn't matter if the method is called more than once after the exception. If it matters, it will be

```
myObject.move(anyString());
expectLastCall().andThrow(new RetryableDependencyException());
myObject.move(anyString());
```

Interesting facts:

- You can chain andReturn
- I highly suggest static imports to get a cleaner code
- anyString is used to prevent the cast in String
- once() is not required as it is the default
- expectLastCall isn't required, calling the void method is enough to record a call without any side effect (like a throw)